# Color coding matplotlib markers

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I'm trying to color-code the markers of my plot.

The idea is that there are x,y, and z values -- x and y containing coordinates, z containing a number corresponding to each coordinate (i.e., x,y-pair) between 0 and 150.

Now, I need to plot a square for each coordinate, which I accomplish with `pyplot.plot(x,y, ls='s')`, where I can set the marker edge and face color separately. Usually, all of those square have the same color.

What I am trying is to change the color according to the z-value, for example

z=0-30: black, 30-60: blue, 60-90: green, 90-120: yellow, 120-150: red

I tried binning the data to those bins, but i have no idea how to map that to the colors and plot it accordingly.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15554939/932593

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, I will check on it!

Comment: This would be similar (except I don't want to plot an image), but as described in the comment below, I get the error, with c=colors and colors being my list of z values, that c must be two dimensional. In all the examples I found, this is not the case.

Comment: Got it. workt with `sc = plt.scatter(...)` and `plt.colorbar(sc)`

Answer (score 2):

Store those X,Y coordinates in separate X,Y's (1 pair for each Z range), then plot them all by multiple plot lines.

Conceptual example:

```
X1,Y1 = """store your Z0-30 here"""
X2,Y2 = """store your z30-60 here"""
X3,Y3 = """store your z60-z90 here"""
X4,Y4 = """store your z90-120 here"""
X5,Y5 = """store your z120-150 here"""
fig=plt.figure()
pyplot.plot(X1,Y1,color='black')
pyplot.plot(X2,Y2,color='blue')
pyplot.plot(X3,Y3,color='green')
pyplot.plot(X4,Y4,color='yellow')
pyplot.plot(X5,Y5,color='red')
plt.show()
```

I would suggest using a [scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) plot, it sounds a lot more suited to what you describe. Change pyplot.plot to pyplot.scatter in that case. You can use a cmap to colour them by Z axis. You could also assign custom markers to each group as displayed in [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_custom_symbol.html) example.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I do not want to do - assigning it manually to bins and then to colors.

Comment: Use the scatter plot then as I suggested as well

Comment: The problem with scatter is, that I cannot change the edge thickness of the square marker, only the size. I need a specific square size and shape (ideally defined in axis units, but there seems to be no easy way to do that).

Comment: @Frixhax Make your own marker? Check out this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_custom_symbol.html

Comment: Nice, thanks. However, when I try the way shown here <http://stackoverflow.com/q/15554939/932593> with `colorss=np.random.randn(100) cm=cm.hot scatter(x, y, c=colors, marker='s', cmap=cm)` I get the error _raise ValueError("Color array must be two-dimensional")_